# Using v-for for fixed numbers and not objects

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to render a simple table with 20 rows and 5 columns with `v-for` but I'm having problems. My code:

```
<tr v-for="row in totalRows" :key="row">
    <td v-for="col in totalColumns" :key="col">
        {{ getTableNum() }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

In data:

```
totalColumns: 5,
totalRows: 20,
numberCount: 0,
```

Method:

```
getTableNum() {
  return ++this.numberCount;
},
```

It is throwing a warning...

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

... and rendering like 20k rows.

I can't find an example on how use `v-for` for fixed numbers(only using objects) anywhere.

I imagine that those loops above would reproduce a result like:

```
for (let row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < totalCols; col++) {
        getTableNum();
    }
}
```

But I'm wrong for some reason.

UPDATE: Ended up using no variables at all:

```
<tr v-for="row in 20" :key="row">
    <td v-for="col in 5" :key="col">
        {{ col + (row - 1) * 5 }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I wish official docs could have examples like that. If I knew that fixed numbers could be used in the for loop it would spare me some time.

Comment: How does `getTableNum` method look?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim updated the question with that method.

Comment: and where you use `numberCount`? and why you're incrementing?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim only to show numbers in table cells. Nowhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running methods inside the template leads to some infinite rendering loops since the variable is also used in template, to avoid this create a two-dimensional array as a computed property and then render it :

```
computed:{
   arr(){
    let n=0;
   return [...Array(20)].map((_,i)=>[...Array(5)].map((_,j)=>{
       ++n;
      return n;
   }))
 
  }
}
```

in template :

```
<tr v-for="(row,i) in arr" :key="i">
    <td v-for="col in row" :key="col">
        {{ col }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `numberCount` (which is a reactive data property) directly in the template. That triggers a re-render (and thus an infinite loop). You can simply do this :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    totalColumns: 5,
    totalRows: 20
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table border=1>
    <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in totalRows" :key="row">
        <td v-for="(col, columnIndex) in totalColumns" :key="col">
          {{ rowIndex * totalColumns + col}}
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getTableNum` function execution changes the `numberCount` in data and it triggers Vue to re-render the template, which causes the function execution, and so on.

In this case, you should try to avoid altering the `numberCount` value.

If I didn't get you wrong, you wish to have `1-2-3-4-5` in the first row, `6-7-8-9-10` in the second, and so on.

If so, you can try to rewrite your function as such:

```
getTableNum(row, col) {
    // row and col are 1-based
    return 1 + ((row - 1) * this.totalColumns) + (col - 1);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative ONLY for static tables (where the table content is not modified after initial rendering) is the use of `v-once` directive. Each table row will be rendered only once, and every subsequent call to `getTableNum` function will not trigger the rerendering of previous rows:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    totalColumns: 5,
    totalRows: 20,
    numberCount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    getTableNum() {
      return ++this.numberCount
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table border=1>
    <tr v-once v-for="(row, rowIndex) in totalRows" :key="row">
        <td v-for="(col, columnIndex) in totalColumns" :key="col">
         {{ getTableNum() }}
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats very interesting! Thank you for your input.